# Como manipular a pilha FPU no assembly x86 usando o NASM e funções em c?

Tags: assembly, x86, ponto-flutuante

Estou tentando fazer essa operação (y = 0.299*red + 0.587*green + 0.114*blue) em assembly modo protegido nasm integrando c com assembly no windows, porém o independentemente dos valores de entrada o resultado sempre é 0.

```
extern printf  ;a função printf em C é chamada
extern scanf   ;a função scanf em C é chamada

SECTION .data

msg1 db "Pixel vai ficar preto!", 10,0
msg2 db "Pixel vai ficar branco!", 10,0
msg3 db "Digite os valores para as cores vermelho, verde e azul:", 10,0
scan db "%d", 0
;msg4 db "Os numeros sao %d, %d, %d", 0
msg5 db "valor final %.3f",10,0
constante1 dd 0.299
constante2 dd 0.587
constante3 dd 0.114
constante4 dd 0.713
constante5 dd 128
constante6 dd 0.564
;y dw 0

SECTION .bss
red resd 1
green resd 1
blue resd 1
y resd 1
cr resd 1
cb resd 1

SECTION .text


_start:
push msg3
call printf
add esp, 4

;pega o valor de vermelho
push red
push scan
call scanf
add esp, 8

;pega o valor de verde
push green
push scan
call scanf
add esp, 8

;pega o valor de azul
push blue
push scan
call scanf
add esp, 8


;imprime os valores lidos (só pra teste)
;push dword[blue]
;push dword[green]
;push dword[red]
;push msg4
;call printf
;add esp, 16

calcula_y:


fld dword[red]          ;coloca na pilha o valor de red
fld dword[constante1]       ;coloca na pilha o valor da constate1
fmulp st1,st0           ;faz a multiplicação e salva em st1

fld dword[green]        ;coloca na pilha o valor de green
fld dword[constante2]       ;coloca na pilha o valor da constate2
fmulp st1,st0           ;faz a multiplicação e salva em st1

fld dword[blue]         ;coloca na pilha o valor de blue
fld dword[constante3]       ;coloca na pilha o valor da constate3
fmulp st1,st0           ;faz a multiplicação e salva em st1

faddp st1, st0          ;faz a adição de st1 e st0 e salva em st1 e dá um pop em st0
fadd st1            ;faz a adição de st1 e st0 e salva em st0
fst dword[y]            ;pega o valor st0 e coloca em y

push dword[y+4]
push dword[y]
push msg5
call printf
add esp, 12



ret
```

Answer (score 2):

A lógica no uso da FPU está correta.

Existem apenas dois problemas no programa:

**1) Carga dos dados para a FPU**

Ao executar a função `scanf` para efetuar a leitura dos dados, a string de formatação informada é `%d`, portanto, o resultado da leitura irá armazenar um número inteiro na memória de destino.

Ao carregar esse número para a FPU como, por exemplo, na linha `fld dword[red]`, a FPU espera encontrar um número em formato [Ponto Flutuante](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponto_flutuante), e não um inteiro.

A solução é alterar a string de formatação `scan` para `"%f"`.

**2) Armazenamento do resultado calculado na memória**

A FPU está tentando armazenar um resultado no formato `qword`, porém, você especificou o endereço de destino como `dword`.

Como o valor a ser armazenado é maior que o destino, a FPU aciona uma exceção do tipo `#P`, que conforme o manual da Intel:

> "Value cannot be represented exactly in destination format."

A solução é trocar o prefixo `dword` para `qword`.

Segue abaixo, o programa já com essas correções:

```
global _main
extern _printf  ;a função _printf em C é chamada
extern _scanf   ;a função _scanf em C é chamada

SECTION .data

msg1        db  "Pixel vai ficar preto!", 10,0
msg2        db  "Pixel vai ficar branco!", 10,0
msg3        db  "Digite os valores para as cores vermelho, verde e azul:", 10,0
scan        db  "%f", 0 ; tem que ser %f!!!!

;msg4 db "Os numeros sao %d, %d, %d", 0
msg5        db "valor final %.3f",10,0
constante1  dd 0.299
constante2  dd 0.587
constante3  dd 0.114
constante4  dd 0.713
constante5  dd 128
constante6  dd 0.564
;y dw 0

SECTION .bss

red         resd 1
green       resd 1
blue        resd 1
y           resd 1
cr          resd 1
cb          resd 1

SECTION .text

_main:
            ; Aqui, precisa salvar o stack frame
            push        ebp
            mov         ebp, esp

            push        msg3
            call        _printf
            add         esp, 4

            ;pega o valor de vermelho
            push        red
            push        scan
            call        _scanf
            add         esp, 8

            ;pega o valor de verde
            push        green
            push        scan
            call        _scanf
            add         esp, 8

            ;pega o valor de azul
            push        blue
            push        scan
            call        _scanf
            add         esp, 8


;imprime os valores lidos (só pra teste)
;push dword[blue]
;push dword[green]
;push dword[red]
;push msg4
;call _printf
;add esp, 16

calcula_y:

            fld         dword[red]          ;coloca na pilha o valor de red
            fld         dword[constante1]   ;coloca na pilha o valor da constate1
            fmulp       st1, st0            ;faz a multiplicação e salva em st1

            fld         dword[green]        ;coloca na pilha o valor de green
            fld         dword[constante2]   ;coloca na pilha o valor da constate2
            fmulp       st1, st0            ;faz a multiplicação e salva em st1

            fld         dword[blue]         ;coloca na pilha o valor de blue
            fld         dword[constante3]   ;coloca na pilha o valor da constate3
            fmulp       st1, st0            ;faz a multiplicação e salva em st1

            faddp       st1, st0            ;faz a adição de st1 e st0 e salva em st1 e dá um pop em st0
            faddp       st1                 ;faz a adição de st1 e st0 e salva em st0
            fst         qword[y]            ; Aqui, tem que ser QWORD

            push        dword[y+4]
            push        dword[y]
            push        msg5
            call        _printf
            ;call        _scanf
            add         esp, 12

            mov         esp, ebp
            pop         ebp
            ret
```

O programa foi compilado com `NASM version 2.11.08`, através do comando:

`nasm -g -f win32 xx.asm`

E linkado com `Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.23506.0`, através do comando:

`link /debug:FULL /libpath:"caminho_para_o_dir_lib_do_msvc" /subsystem:CONSOLE xx.obj "libcmt.lib" "advapi32.lib" "legacy_stdio_definitions.lib"`

Trocar *caminho_para_o_dir_lib_do_msvc* para o diretório `lib` dentro da instalação do MSVC.

Para o processo de debug durante a análise, foi utilizado o programa: [x64dbg](http://x64dbg.com/) (versão de 32 bits).

Após a execução, o resultado do programa foi:

```
Digite os valores para as cores vermelho, verde e azul:
100.0
101.0
102.0
valor final 100.815
```

Observação: para efetuar o processo de link sem erros, foi necessário acrescentar o underline `'_'` antes das funções.

Para maiores referências, consultar os manuais (em PDF):
[Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html)